# "no such file to load -- pg" when trying rake db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rubygems

The symptom of my problem is pretty simple:

```
$ rake db:create
(in /home/jason/projects/blog)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- pg

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've already successfully run `bundle install` and `gem install pg`, so I don't know what else I might need to do.

Here's my `config/database.yml if it helps:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: foo

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password: foo

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. If I use `pg` instead of `postgresql` in my `config/database.yml`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to console and type below:

```
vim Gemfile
```

Inside the file commend the below:

```
- #gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

Inside the file add the below:

```
- gem 'pg', :require => 'pg'
```

Problem Solved!!! :-) Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the rake binary that you are running is from another ruby/gem environment and that it doesn't have access to the gems that you've installed.

If you have more than one version of ruby installed, try running `which gem` and then `which rake` to see if they are being run from the same bin directory. For example, on my machine both binaries are executed from bin directories under the same Ruby install:

```
/Users/scott/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/gem

/Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rake
```

If you only have one ruby version installed on your system, then this isn't the answer!